# Fatal RunTime Error while running SampleApp

Tags: android, runtime

[The file that is causing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XvNZ.png)

I am having the following error when I am trying to execute the application of sampleapp provided by researchstack:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: org.researchstack.sampleapp, PID: 24072
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.

And it is caused by:

> Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.researchstack.sampleapp.bridge.UploadRequest$$Configuration

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code that caused the error.

Comment: The link of the file is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XvNZ.png

Comment: Don't add a photo of your code or a link to your code, rather add your code to the question.

Comment: Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2293). It might be related to your own issue.

Comment: can anyone help please???